# How to restrict upload image type in tinymce-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce-4

I am using (Rails 5):

```
gem 'tinymce-rails', '>= 4.4.0'
gem 'tinymce-rails-imageupload', '~> 4.0.0.beta'
```

I would like to somehow restrict the filetype of an uploaded image - as JPEG, PNG, GIF etc. Now the user can upload any filetype (even non-images) - with any extension.

How to do that correctly?

Comment: I don't understand why my question was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
class TinymceAssetsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Take upload from params[:file] and store it somehow...
    # Optionally also accept params[:hint] and consume if needed

    fname = params[:file].original_filename

    ri = fname.rindex(".")    

    if ri && (['gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'svg'].include? fname[fname.rindex(".")+1..-1])

      image = Image.create file: params[:file]    

      render json: {
        image: {
          url: image.file.url
        }
      }, content_type: "text/html"

    else

      render json: {
        error: {
          message: "Invalid file type. <br>Only .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif, .svg allowed"
        }
      }, content_type: "text/html"

    end

  end
end
```